# Can dedicated DHCP server assign a default gateway address to router?

Tags: dhcp

I have built a very simple LAN in Packet Tracer: a PC, a dedicated DHCP server, a switch and a router.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvx3X.jpg - here is this LAN

The router is meant to be a default gateway in the LAN, and all I want is that the DHCP server would always assign a default gateway address, that it sends to all devices in the LAN, to the router. Router FastEthernet port is configured to get an address from the DHCP server too, using:

```
Router(config-if)#ip address dhcp
```

Is it possible to do so, and if yes, how? If no, why? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what DHCP server code you're running, but it's definitely something allowed for in the DHCP spec.  In ISC's dhcpd, you'd use the `routers` option, perhaps as follows:

```
subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.3.101 192.168.3.200 ;
 option routers 192.168.3.1 ;
 [...]
}
```

which will set the default route for all the clients to `192.168.3.1`.

Since your router also gets its address via DHCP, you'll need to set up a special lease for the router's MAC address, so that it always gets the `192.168.3.1` address (to match that set in the `routers` option above), and so that it doesn't get fed its own address as a default route.

Comment: Thank you! I have just read Packet Tracer's help section on Servers, and there's not a word about how to configure DHCP leases in the DHCP subsection of that help page. It's probably not possible with dedicated DHCP in PT.